# Library call in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to replace library call in HTML by library call in JS ?

For example here, is it possible to delete `<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/projet/libs/libraryexample.js"></script>` from HTML and call it JS file instead ?

```
    <head>
        <title>pagetest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/projet/libs/libraryexample.js"></script>
        <script lang="javascript" src="./myjs.js"></script>
    </head>
```

and the JS file:

```
var myObject = new ObjectFromMyLibraryExample();
var myPart = myObject.addText("hello");
```

I have tried `import "libraryexample"` but it didn't work and I don't know how to do.

Comment: Well of course you could create the script element that loads the library dynamically (which makes everything more complicated as it becomes asynchronous), but there's no good reason not to just do it in the html.

Comment: `import` didn't work because you probably(?) didn't transpile it. It doesn't necessarily work out of the box.  More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: It is just for learning and understand (even if it is not the best solution). So what would the command be ? I had a look to the link you give jmargolistvt but I don't understand how to use import in that case ? What do you mean when you say `import "libraryexample"` didn't work because I don't transpile it ?